# How to change the location of a picture box in VB 2010 using the arrow or wasd keys?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, location

I only have access to the internet at school, so the filters get in the way of any real research. I'm currently coding an rpg for a school project but it's difficult to get the avatar to move on a map. Here's my pathetic code so far:

```
Public Class Map1

    Private Sub USER_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
        User.Top = User.Top - 1
    End Sub

    Private Sub USER_KeyUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyUp
        User.Top = User.Bottom + 1
        'User.Location.X = 200
    End Sub
End Class
```

I have the following problems with it:
User.location.x = 200  had syntax errors when I deleted the x and when I didn't.
The player also had to continually press the keys to move.

both I do not know how to correct.
Any help at all is greatly appreciated as it's for my final grade.

Answer (score 2):

You can put it in a `timer_tick` to loop over it, that is what I do.

And the correct version of `User.Location.X = 200` is:

```
User.location = new point(200, User.location.y)
```

Answer (score 0):

nvm found the solution.
Here it is for anyone else how might need the code in the future.

```
Private Sub Map_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Up Then
        User.Location = New Point(User.Location.X, User.Location.Y - 5)
    ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.Down Then
        User.Location = New Point(User.Location.X, User.Location.Y + 5)
    ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.Left Then
        User.Location = New Point(User.Location.X - 5, User.Location.Y)
    ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.Right Then
        User.Location = New Point(User.Location.X + 5, User.Location.Y)
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Module

    Public Sub MovePictureBox(ByRef PictureBox As PictureBox)
        Tiempo.Tag = PictureBox
        AddHandler PictureBox.Parent.KeyDown, AddressOf Parent_KeyDown
        AddHandler PictureBox.Parent.KeyUp, AddressOf Parent_KeyUp
        AddHandler CType(PictureBox.Parent, Form).Load, AddressOf Parent_Load
    End Sub
    Private Up, Down, Left, Right As Boolean
    WithEvents Tiempo As New Timer() With {.Interval = 1}
    Private Sub Tiempo_Tick() Handles Tiempo.Tick
        If Up Then Tiempo.Tag.Top -= 2
        If Down Then Tiempo.Tag.Top += 2
        If Left Then Tiempo.Tag.Left -= 2
        If Right Then Tiempo.Tag.Left += 2
    End Sub
    Private Sub Parent_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs)
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Up Then Up = True
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Down Then Down = True
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Left Then Left = True
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Right Then Right = True
        Tiempo.Enabled = True
    End Sub
    Private Sub Parent_KeyUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs)
        Tiempo.Enabled = False
        Up = False : Down = False : Right = False : Left = False
    End Sub
    Private Sub Parent_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        sender.KeyPreview = True
    End Sub
End Module
```